# UWP SQLite DB OneDrive Backup and Restore C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, backup, onedrive

I would like to backup an existing localfolder SQLite DB within my UWP app to the user's OneDrive on button click and then when the same UWP app is installed onto another PC by the same user, restore the database back into the UWP app so that they have the same data in all devices where they may install the UWP app.   I don't need anything complex. Just sweet and simple C# code.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, I recommend you use [OneDrive Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive) to backup your data, you could use it to create update and download file with onedrive api. You could also use `RoamingFolder` to store your data that could roaming automatically. For more info please refer [**Roaming data**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#roaming-data).

Comment: I thought about using the Roaming Data folder initially but since the database grows beyond the 200K limit, it will not work for me.

Comment: If your item beyond the 200k, pleas use OneDrive Service to backup your data.

Comment: I decided I will go a slightly different route now. I just want to save the UWP sqlite db data using filepicker.   The database resides in the localfolder.   Does anyone have code for this?

Comment: Basically I just want to be able to backup the UWP SQLite database from the localfolder within the app to a folder location the user selects and give it a default extension and let the user chose the filename.   Then if they so chose later on, to be able to open the location using a button click and restore the database back to it's original location after choosing the file again from where they saved it.

Comment: I actually solved the issue myself and can now backup and restore my UWP SQLite databases.

Comment: @DharkUndercity:  Could you please explain how you solved this issue. Noting you solved it does not help me (nor anyone else)  any further.